# Update Dynamics GP web references

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to update a web service project that was previously built with GP 2010, to GP 2015. I have made the new Service Reference class, and a WebService.svc to interface with it.

Here is my project structure:

[image]

Navigating to http://localhost:48620/DynamicsGpWebServices I get:

```
svcutil.exe http://1bqryz1:48620/Metadata/Legacy/Full/DynamicsGP.wsdl
```

And navigating to http://localhost:48620/Dynamics/gpservice I get:

```
svcutil.exe http://1bqryz1:48620/Metadata/WCF/Full/schemas.microsoft.com.dynamics.gp.2010.01.wsdl
```

To me, it looks like DynamicsGpWebService is running  the legacy .net 2.0 ASMX references, and that the second link gives me the new WCF references, however it is still pointing to GP 2010.

Looking through the project and online I can't find any way to update the GP version it is pointing to. I have GP 2015 installed, as well as the web services run-time.

Am I missing something here? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, managed to find some more resources on it and it looks like it's OK.

The address

```
 http://localhost:48620/DynamicsGpWebServices
```

is pointing to the legacy endpoint, while

```
http://localhost:48620/Dynamics/gpservice
```

is pointing to the native endpoint, despite the fact it states

```
dynamics.gp.2010.01.wsdl
```

to run it with svcutil.exe.

You can verify that it is the right version of GP web services by going to local services and finding Microsoft Dynamics GP Service Host.

More information can be found [here](http://www.azurecurve.co.uk/2015/08/hands-on-with-microsoft-dynamics-gp-2015-r2-web-services-verification/)